# Does VSCode support IntelliSense for Maven projects?

Tags: java, maven, visual-studio-code, code-completion

I was able to get red squiggly lines for erroneous code while working on a Java project that used Gradle with VSCode. However, for a Maven-based project I didn't get any such highlighting. Does VSCode actually support Maven projects?

Answer (score 1):

The [vscode-java](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=redhat.java) extension does support Maven and Gradle java projects.

If you have any trouble, you can open bug reports to its [issue tracker on GitHub](https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/issues).